# How to give a random entity a certain effect after delay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
execute at @a if score @p delay matches 50 run execute at @e[sort=random,limit=1] run effect give @s glowing
```

This is the command I have so far, I also have a delay command constantly running. I set the delay to 0 and also tested the command to give *myself* items if the delay is 50, using the same command. The command is working and it detects that the delay is at 50, but when targeting `@e` by random and using `@s` to give it an effect, for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @s selector refers to the entity executing the command. In your case, the command is being executed by the command block, so the @s selector doesn't do anything.

You need to tell the command block which entity is executing the command in order to use the @s selector. You can do that using `as <entity>`. Also, you can make your command shorter and simpler by using the `@e[sort=random,limit=1]` selector directly in the /effect command. Example:

```
/execute as @a if score @s delay matches 50 run effect give @e[sort=random,limit=1] glowing
```

This command is saying: "execute the command from every player, test if the player's score on the delay objective matches 50, and if it does, give one random entity the glowing effect".

I recommend taking a look at [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) wiki page if you want to learn more about selectors.